# CakePHP custom search

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Hey guys im trying to create an advance  search form in cakephp,

Form consist in Dropdowns,  Checkboxes (HABTM relations), Textfield, and price ranger (slider),
You can see the form below:

[image]

As you can see i have multiple dropdown , multiple checkbox etc.

The search works great but what i want is how can i save these changes or filters on url for example after the user has selected a few filters as follow:

[image]

I want the url to be  as  follow :
http://localhost/website/cakephpapplication/search?location=something&room_type=sth&accommodation_type=something&.... 
and so one

The Action  that i use is this one:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function search() {
        $this->layout = 'frontend_search';
        $default_lang_code = Configure::read('Config.language');
        if($this->Session->check('Config.language')) { // Check for existing language session
            $language_code = $this->Session->read('Config.language'); // Read existing language
            $languageData  = $this->Language->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Language.language_code'=>$language_code),'recursive' => -1,'fields' => array('Language.id'),'limit' => 1));
            if (!empty($languageData)) {
                $language_id = $languageData['Language']['id'];
            } else {
                $language_id =  $this->Language->findLanguageIdByCode($default_lang_code);
            }
        } else {
            $language_code = $default_lang_code; // Read existing language
            $languageData = $this->Language->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Language.language_code'=>$default_lang_code),'recursive' => -1,'fields' => array('Language.id'),'limit' => 1));
            $language_id = $languageData['Language']['id'];
        }

        $localeCurrency = 'EUR';        
        if ($this->Session->check('LocaleCurrency')) {
            $localeCurrency = $this->Session->read('LocaleCurrency');
        } 

        $currencies  = $this->Currency->find('all', array( 'recursive'=>-1));

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(!empty($this->request->data)){
                /*THIS IS THE MOS REQUESTED PROPERTIES */
                $searchQuery  =" SELECT  Property.* , PropertyTranslation.*, Wishlist.*, Currency.*";
                $searchQuery .=" FROM properties as Property";
                $searchQuery .=" JOIN property_translations as PropertyTranslation";
                $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = PropertyTranslation.property_id";
                $searchQuery .=" JOIN users as User";
                $searchQuery .=" ON User.id = Property.user_id";

                $searchQuery .=" LEFT JOIN wishlists as Wishlist";
                $searchQuery .=" ON Wishlist.property_id = Property.id ";
                $searchQuery .=" LEFT JOIN currencies as Currency";
                $searchQuery .=" On Currency.id = Property.currency_id";

                if (isset($this->request->data['Safety']) && !empty($this->request->data['Safety']) && $this->request->data['Safety']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .=" JOIN  properties_safeties as PropertiesSafety";
                    $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = PropertiesSafety.property_id";
                    foreach ($this->request->data['Safety'] as $key => $value) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND PropertiesSafety.safety_id = '".$value."'";
                    }
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Extra']) && !empty($this->request->data['Extra']) && $this->request->data['Extra']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .=" JOIN  extras_properties as ExtrasProperty";
                    $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = ExtrasProperty.property_id";
                    foreach ($this->request->data['Extra'] as $key => $value) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND ExtrasProperty.extra_id = '".$value."'";
                    }
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Service']) && !empty($this->request->data['Service']) && $this->request->data['Service']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .=" JOIN  properties_services as PropertiesService";
                    $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = PropertiesService.property_id";
                    foreach ($this->request->data['Service'] as $key => $value) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND PropertiesService.service_id = '".$value."'";
                    }
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Characteristic']) && !empty($this->request->data['Characteristic']) && $this->request->data['Characteristic']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .=" JOIN  characteristics_properties as CharacteristicsProperty";
                    $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = CharacteristicsProperty.property_id";
                    foreach ($this->request->data['Characteristic'] as $key => $value) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND CharacteristicsProperty.characteristic_id = '".$value."'";
                    }
                }

                $searchQuery .=" WHERE Property.property_status=1 AND Property.publish_status=1 AND User.is_first_post=0  AND PropertyTranslation.language_id='".$language_id."' ";
                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['capacity']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['capacity']) && $this->request->data['Property']['capacity']!='') {
                      $searchQuery .= " AND Property.capacity ='".$this->request->data['Property']['capacity']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['address']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['address']) && trim($this->request->data['Property']['address'])!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.address  LIKE '%".$this->request->data['Property']['address']."%' ";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['capacity']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['capacity']) && $this->request->data['Property']['capacity']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.capacity ='".$this->request->data['Property']['capacity']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['room_number']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['room_number']) && $this->request->data['Property']['room_number']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.room_number ='".$this->request->data['Property']['room_number']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['bed_number']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['bed_number']) && $this->request->data['Property']['bed_number']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.bed_number ='".$this->request->data['Property']['bed_number']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['bathroom_number']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['bathroom_number']) && $this->request->data['Property']['bathroom_number']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.bathroom_number ='".$this->request->data['Property']['bathroom_number']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['property_type'])!='' && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['property_type']) && trim($this->request->data['Property']['property_type'])!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.property_type  LIKE '%".$this->request->data['Property']['property_type']."%'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['property_type'])!='' && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['property_type']) && $this->request->data['Property']['property_type']=='sale') {

                    if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['surface_area'])!='' && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['surface_area'])) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND Property.surface_area  = '".$this->request->data['Property']['surface_area']."'";
                    }

                    if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['sale_price'])!='' && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['sale_price'])) {
                        $searchQuery .= " AND Property.sale_price  = '".$this->request->data['Property']['sale_price']."'";
                    }


                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['room_type_id']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['room_type_id']) && $this->request->data['Property']['room_type_id']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.room_type_id = '".$this->request->data['Property']['room_type_id']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['accommodation_type_id']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['accommodation_type_id']) && $this->request->data['Property']['accommodation_type_id']!='') {
                    $searchQuery .= " AND Property.accommodation_type_id = '".$this->request->data['Property']['accommodation_type_id']."'";
                }

                if (isset($this->request->data['Property']['price']) && !empty($this->request->data['Property']['price']) && $this->request->data['Property']['price']!='') {
                    $price = $this->request->data['Property']['price'];
                    list($minPrice, $maxPrice) = explode(";", $price);
                    $searchQuery .= " AND  Property.rent_daily_price BETWEEN '".$minPrice."' AND '".$maxPrice."'";
                }

                $searchQuery .=" ORDER BY Property.id";
                $searchResults = $this->Property->query($searchQuery);
            }
        } else {
            $searchQuery  =" SELECT  Property.*, PropertyTranslation.*, Wishlist.*, Currency.* ";
            $searchQuery .=" FROM properties as Property";
            $searchQuery .=" JOIN property_translations as PropertyTranslation";
            $searchQuery .=" ON Property.id = PropertyTranslation.property_id";
            $searchQuery .=" JOIN users as User";
            $searchQuery .=" ON User.id = Property.user_id";

            $searchQuery .=" LEFT JOIN wishlists as Wishlist";
            $searchQuery .=" ON Wishlist.property_id = Property.id ";

            $searchQuery .=" LEFT JOIN currencies as Currency";
            $searchQuery .=" On Currency.id = Property.currency_id";

            $searchQuery .=" WHERE Property.property_status=1 AND Property.publish_status=1 AND User.is_first_post=0  AND PropertyTranslation.language_id='".$language_id."'";
            $searchQuery .=" ORDER BY Property.id";
            $searchResults = $this->Property->query($searchQuery);
        }

        $this->set(compact('searchResults','roomTypes','accommodationTypes','safeties','extras','services','characteristics','currencies'));
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The search works great but what i want is how can i save these changes or filters on url for example after the user has selected a few filters as follow:

You want to implement [the PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) that turns POST into GET.

Do it yourself, the wiki article explains the pattern, or use an existing plugin:

- https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search
- https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Comment: @buruzum im sorry but i don't get it, how can i implement those plugins to  my application ?

Comment: Read the provided documentation and the CakePHP book on how to use plugins? Both plugins come with documentation and code examples.

Comment: thanx for your replay, i tried this plugin but wasnt exacly what i wanted so  i managed to solve it by myself  in a work around. :))

Comment: Why aren't they? They do exactly what you want or try to do.